# What is the most efficient way to calculate the highest density given n number of double numbers and a double window

Tags: algorithm, c++11

This problem may be similar to some existing density problems. 
Imagine an input file with n entries when n is unsigned long.
What is the best efficient way to read the file and find the window with most density. If there are more than one window with highest equal density then all windows must be printed as output.
For example for input file:

1.02, 1.03, 5.00, -1.30, -1.10, 1.00, 1.01, 1.04, 1.05, 1.06, 2.00, 2.10, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.01, 5.01, 8.00, 8.01, 8,02, 1000.00, 1000.00, 1000.00, 1000.01, 1000.01, 1000.02, 1000.07

If window = 0.00 the most density would be at 5.00 with 4 density:
          [5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00]

If window =  0.05 then there would be 5 windows with most density :

```
      [5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.00, 5.01, 5.01]
      [1.00, 1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05]
      [1.01, 1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.06]
      [1.02, 1.03, 1.04, 1.05, 1.06, 1.07]
      [1000.00, 1000.00, 1000.00, 1000.01, 1000.01, 1000.02]
```

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: Considering that you have been a member for over four years, you have had plenty of time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). You should also [know how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The question is good, but all you need to show here is little bit of your effort.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually solve this by implicitly building a corresponding mathematical function:

```
P = the set of points
f(x) = amount({p | x in [p, p + L]})
```

We can simulate this function in the following way:

- sort the list of points, if hey aren't yet sorted
- traverse from left to right. If a point is encountered, increment a counter by 1, if `p + L` is encountered, decrement the pointer by 1. Store the location of the interval for which the counter maximizes

As pseudocode:

```
list p = sort(list(P))

queue q
int count = 0

range max = (-1, -1, 0)


while !p.empty:
    if q.empty || q.peek() > p[0]:
        count++

        if max.count < count
            max = (p[0], -1, count)

        q.push(p[0] + L)
        p.remove(0)
    elif q.peek() < p[0]:
        count--

        if max.end == -1:
            max.end = q.peek()

        q.pop()
        count--
    else:
        q.pop()
        p.remove(0)
```

The basic idea of this algorithm is to build a histogram for `f` and search for the highest section. `q` stores the end-points of intervals defined by `[p, p + L]`, `p` the start-points.